# How to register plot or label click event in chart.js

Tags: select, plot, label, chart.js

Now I am using Chart.js lib.
And want to register click event handler to run my custom code.
[image]

```
var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: label,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Logined users num",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    data: data
                }]
            },
});
```

I want to run my custom code when I click a label or a plot.

And when click them, how to get information about them.

ex) When I click "2016-11-16" label, how to get "2016-11-16" string value.

ex) When I click plot (2016-11-19,4), how to get plot info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### onCLick Event

> Called if the event is of type 'mouseup' or 'click'. Called in the
>   context of the chart and passed an array of active elements

When you click on point it will call the function by passing two parameters mouseEvent and an array of a chart. From chart array, you can extract the label.

```
 options: {
        onClick : function(mouseEvent,chart){

        }
    }
```

[**Sample-code**]

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1");
var label = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
var data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: label,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Logined users num",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    data: data
                }]
            },
             options: {
        onClick : function(mouseEvent,chart){
               var myLabel = label[chart[0]._index];
               var y = this.data.datasets[chart[0]._datasetIndex].data[chart[0]._index];
            }
        }

});
```

P.S :- It will only work if you click on chart or points not for label.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, _model have not label attribute.
I added more code, please help me

Comment: @WhiteSnow please find the updated code. It will give you the plot when click on any point.

Comment: What happens if user clicks on X Axis label, can we able to print the label now?